# Android: AsyncTask - onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

Please help, I have this code, and there arises a problem.

```
public class AdvertShowDetail extends Activity {
public String advert_id;
public TextView advert_title;
public LinearLayout advert_table;

public JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
public JSONArray Events   = null;

public String item_name;
public ProgressDialog pDialog;
public Object item_title;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_advert_show_detail);

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle("Advert");

    Intent intent   = getIntent();
    Bundle extras   = intent.getExtras();
    advert_id       = extras.getString("ITEM_ID");
    advert_title    = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    new LoadAdvertInfo().execute();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.advert_show_detail, menu);
    return true;
}

class LoadAdvertInfo extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AdvertShowDetail.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Načítám detaily inzerátu.");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        JSONObject json            = jParser.makeHttpRequest("http://192.168.2.200/app/?type=get_advert_detail&id="+advert_id, "GET", params);
        try {
            int success = json.getInt("success");

            if (success == 1) {
                Events = json.getJSONArray("item");
                for (int i = 0; i < Events.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject evt = Events.getJSONObject(i);

                    item_name = evt.getString("name");
                    Log.e("Advert", item_name);
                }
            } else {
                //
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.e("Test", item_name);
        advert_title.setText("Test");
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

}

In this application, the application crashes when loading activities.
But if **advert_title.setText("Test");** To remove the activity loads fine. Just how differently I write text in TextView when I'm not working this way?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: show your xml, from your comments `findViewById(R.id.textView1)` must be returning null. OTherwise show us your LogCat stacktrace

Comment: Thank you very much, I totally forgot that this variable was not defined in the layout. Should I really have to sleep :D Such a shame:(

Answer (score 0):

try passing advert_title instead into your AsyncTask by:

```
    new LoadAdvertInfo(advert_title).execute();
```

and adding a constructor inside your LoadAdvertInfo class.

Alternatively, you may pass it inside execute.

Answer (score -2):

If I recall correctly, you are not supposed to update the User Interface (UI) when you run an AsyncTask since an AsyncTask works on a different Thread and not the UI Thread (sometimes referred to as the Main Thread). Seeing that you initialized your textView, try to put your `advert_title.setText("Test");`  after you call `new LoadAdvertInfo().execute();`.